# Is JasperReport 3.1 running with JAVA 8?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm trying to migrate my JAVA 6 project to JAVA 8 but I was wondering if the jasper 3.1 lib is compatible with JAVA 6 and if not, which is the lowest version running JAVA 8.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current Version of JasperReport is V6 which support Java 6 and Higher:

**JasperReports® Library v6 Requirements**

**JRE**

```
Java Runtime Environment 6.0 or higher
```

https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/jasperreports-library-v6-requirements

== Edited ==

Java 8 released March 18, **2014**

JasperReports 3.1 released September 17, **2008**

`JasperReports 3.1` will not support `Java 8`.

Comment: yes of course but do you know if the 3.1 version support JAVA 8 ?

Comment: see edit @Zekitui